# Get data from JSON object using value within

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "sales": [{
        "manager": "alberic",
        "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
        "amount": "300",
        "country": "USA",
        "percent-seller": "30",
        "antiquity": "June 2017",
        "date": "6"
    }, {
        "manager": "support",
        "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
        "amount": "300",
        "country": "UK",
        "percent-seller": "20",
        "antiquity": "June 2017",
        "date": "2"
    }, {
        ...
    }]
}
```

I want to retrieve the objects from `sales` where `manager = "support"` and `date = "2"`. How do I go about this in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use `filter()` method and use your condition inside filter method function will return element if your condition become true otherwise it ignore element.

```js
data=    {"sales": [{
          "manager": "alberic",
          "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
          "amount": "300",
          "country": "USA",
          "percent-seller": "30",
          "antiquity": "June 2017",
          "date": "6"
        }, {
          "manager": "support",
          "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
          "amount": "300",
          "country": "UK",
          "percent-seller": "20",
          "antiquity": "June 2017",
          "date": "2"
        },
       ]
      };


var matchedElements = data.sales.filter(function(element) {
   return (element.manager == 'support' && element.date == '2');
});
                   
console.log(matchedElements);
                    
//if you want to access  surgeon of first element of matchedElements
                    
console.log(matchedElements[0].surgeon);

          
//if you want to access  surgeon of all elements in matchedElements
for(i in matchedElements)           
{
console.log(matchedElements[i].surgeon);
}
```

Comment: thanks but how do I access surgeon from matchedElements after using it?

Comment: I have modified my code for access surgeon from matchedElements  :)

Answer (score 1):

You [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `sales` array.

Make sure to add the polyfill from the above link if you want to support older browsers.

```
var matchingSales = jsonData.sales.filter(function(sale) {
   return sale.manager == 'support' && sale.date == '2';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
  "sales": [{
    "manager": "alberic",
    "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
    "amount": "300",
    "country": "USA",
    "percent-seller": "30",
    "antiquity": "June 2017",
    "date": "6"
  }, {
    "manager": "support",
    "surgeon": "Dr Barry Biggins",
    "amount": "300",
    "country": "UK",
    "percent-seller": "20",
    "antiquity": "June 2017",
    "date": "2"
  }]
};


$.each(data.sales, function(i, v) {

  if (v.manager == 'support' && v.date == '2') {
    console.log(v.manager)
    console.log(v.surgeon)
    console.log(v.amount)
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Iterate over them using `.each()`